# Why does ObjectSpace._id2ref sometimes raise a RangeError?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can use `ObjectSpace._id2ref(n)` to return a reference to an object with object_id n. For example:

```
$ a = "foo"
$ a.object_id
70142658775260
$ ObjectSpace._id2ref(a.object_id)
"foo"
```

I was exploring this and wanted to know what object had object_id `4`, but `ObjectSpace._id2ref(4)` raises the following `RangeError`:

```
RangeError: 0x00000000000004 is not id value
```

My understanding is that before Ruby 2.0, `nil`'s object id was fixed at 4, but in Ruby 2.0 `nil` has object id 8. [There's an explanation for this here](https://binarapps.com/blog/ruby-object-id-mystery).

Is the error raised simply because no object has 4 as a fixed object id? If so, is it possible for some object `foo` to happen to be assigned `object_id` 4 at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, in 2.0 and after, there will be no object with id 4, and it is not possible to create one with that id.

Excluding the special builtin types (`nil`, `false`, `true`, Symbols, and numbers), an object's id is taken from its memory address, and assuming a 32 bit machine, the address needs to have a 4 byte alignment, which means that the last 2 bits of the address will be 0.

If that is the case, then the id 4 would theoretically still be a valid address for an object, and hence a valid id, but that object would live in an invalid memory address, since it would most likely already being used by the [program itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) to run in its virtual address space.